# Accessing Windows Azure Service Management API using Windows Live ID

Tags: rest, azure

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460782) it only seems possible to authenticate against the windows azure service management API by attaching a certificate to each request which I previously have uploaded to the management portal.
The [new management API](http://manage.windowsazure.com) has been built using the service management API, but it uses windows live authentication. Is it possible to use windows live to get the windows azure subscription ID and the certificate, so I can use the same authentication mechanism the management portal uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think that the Service Management API uses Live ID for authentication? It is just the portal that uses Live ID for authentication.

If you dig a bit you will notice that all the service requests from the management portal are made against https://manage.windowsazure.com/Service while [The Base URI for management service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460786.aspx) is: https://management.core.windows.net

So, No, you can't authenticate against the Management API with Live ID. Moreover, it is the Management API is not new. The portal is New. The management API has been there for a while and is updated from time to time to reflect new services that are coming.

**UPDATE AFTER THE 2 COMMENTS**

Following Gaurav's explanation I will just add a simple architecture diagram (super simplified and totally my thought, but this is how would I build it in very minimalistic way):

[User's browser (portal)] ==> Sends XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) to ==> [Portal Service]
then
[Portal service backend] ==> signs request with predefined certificate and sends request to ==> [management.core.windows.net/subscription-id/whatever/service/command]

This actually is a very common practice to provide UI to a (web) service.

This way both conditions are implemented:

1. You use Live ID to authenticate with the portal
2. The Windows Azure Service Management API are yet, still and only protected by a Certificate.

Comment: I was confused because Scott Gu in his blogpost (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/06/07/meet-the-new-windows-azure.aspx) said: The new portal is built on top of a REST-based management API within Windows Azure – and everything you can do through the portal can also be programmed directly against this Web API. I was expecting that I could use the exact same functionality, including authentication.

Comment: In a way Scott Gu is correct. For example, through portal you could create a new cloud service. You could also do the same through REST API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg441304). In fact, the portal internally calls these API. It's just that when you invoke the API from your application, the authentication mechanism is certificate based authentication instead of Live Id based authentication. My guess is that portal internally fetches the certificates and invokes request on your behalf.

Comment: VS is somehow able to send up its own management certificate without a pre-existing certificate. How does that work?